# What is the easiest way to run SW that requires Classis Mac OS 9?

Tags: macos, games, classic-mac-os

I see a few games that only run on Mac OS 9 and I'd like to try them.
However, I run macOS 10.12.2. What could be the easiest way to do it?

Specifically, I'd like to play Bonkheads ;-)

I have my Macbook Pro Retina available

Comment: Can you clarify that you are actually talking about Mac OS 9 (as in the classic Mac OS) or whether you mean Mac OS 10.9 ? If you're referring to the classic Mac OS, can you provide more info such as what devices you have available and perhaps listing some of the games.

Comment: You can give SheepShaver (http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) a try, it emulates Mac OS 9. It works on macOS Sierra (I am using it on mine MacBook). If you don't want to use emulation, then you have to find second hand Macs on eBay or similar that runs Mac OS 9.

Comment: @Monomeeth clarified! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @TomShen - [SheepSaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) is a good option.

Just keep in mind that it only works with Mac OS 9 up to 9.0.4 (so don't fall into the trap of trying to use Mac OS 9.2 - the most popular version of that release).

Also, if you're wanting to find a secondhand Mac that can run Mac OS 9, you also have the option of Macs that could run what was called the *Classic Environment*. This was a compatibility layer for running older Mac applications and was included with PowerPC versions of Mac OS X up to and including Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger. In other words, if you want a dedicated Mac you're not necessarily limited to much older ones that could run Mac OS 9, but also have the option using the last models of the following series:

- Power Mac G5
- Mac mini G4
- iMac G5
- eMac
- iBook
- PowerBook G4

**NOTE: These systems cannot run MacOS 9/Classic applications if running MacOS X Leopard or above!**